# Hadoop Nodemanager and Resourcemanager not starting

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, ubuntu-13.10

I am trying to setup the latest Hadoop 2.2 single node cluster on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit. the OS is a fresh installation, and I have tried using both java-6 64 bit and java-7 64 bit.

After following the steps from [this](http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/) and after failing, from [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) link, I am not able to start `nodemanager` and `resourcemanager` with the command:

```
sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
sudo sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
```

and resource manager with

```
sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager
sudo sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager
```

and both fails with error:

```
starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hduser/yarn/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-ubuntu.out
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/service/CompositeService
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
```

Resource Manager fails with similar error: `NoClassDefFoundError`

I have been trying this for many hours and have tried Google and nothing worked. Please let me know what I have missed. [This](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-mapreduce-user/201203.mbox/%3C4F51169C.6090707@apache.org%3E) and [this](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/ea8lWp2E39VA31biEi0t) link while searching for a solution didn't work.

I have tried using both java-6 and java-7 64 bit, with no success.

**Edit**

The accepted answer managed to get rid of the exception and all the daemons are now starting but there is still an exception while running jobs, mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642862/cannot-initialize-cluster-exception-while-running-job-on-hadoop-2) question

Comment: I wish someone with good knowledge of hadoop answers this. From my side, check if you can find anything after reading this - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those instructions are stale and seem to reflecting one of the very early alpha releases. Make this change: YARN_HOME -> HADOOP_YARN_HOME. The environment variable got renamed a while back. This should fix it for you.

You can use Apache Ambari 1.4.1 that eases installation of Hadoop and many of its ecosystem components. You can see http://docs.hortonworks.com/#2.0 on how to install using Ambari.

Comment: Thanks, the daemons are now starting, but there is an exception while running jobs. Please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642862/cannot-initialize-cluster-exception-while-running-job-on-hadoop-2

Answer (score 0):

you should see this is solution, add $HADOOP_HOME/share/ and its sub-directories.
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/46/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-service-compositeservice-shell-exitcodeexception-classnotfoundexception