# Cannot initialize cluster exception while running job on Hadoop 2

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

[The question is linked to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19571962/915751) All the daemons are running, jps shows:

```
6663 JobHistoryServer
7213 ResourceManager
9235 Jps
6289 DataNode
6200 NameNode
7420 NodeManager
```

but the `wordcount` example keeps on failing with the following exception:

```
ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1234)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Since it says the problem is in configuration, I am posting the configuration files here. The intention is to create a single node cluster.

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
 <configuration>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/home/hduser/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/home/hduser/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
 </configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>Yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Please tell what is missing or what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have uppercased `Yarn`, which is probably why it can not resolve it. Try the lowercase version that is [suggested in the official documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html).

```
<configuration>
  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It worked, changing Yarn to yarn solved the problem and the job ran successfully! Thanks!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses. even my configuration is OK.

Answer (score 21):

I was having similar issue, but yarn was not the issue.
After adding following jars into my classpath issue got resolved:

- hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-76
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-76
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-76

Comment: Did you add the jars using CLASSPATH variable or libjars ?

Comment: just add those lib into yours build path i.e classpath

Comment: If you are using Maven or some other build tool, it's sufficient to specify `hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient` as the only dependency from this list. Both `common` and `shuffle` are `jobclient`'s dependencies, so you don't have to specify them as your project's dependencies.

Comment: @bat_rock, i had the same issue. your solution worked for me :-)

Comment: @neeraj How to add jar files to classpath?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like i had a lucky day and went with this exception through 'all' of those causes. Summary:

- wrong mapreduce.framework.name (see above)
- missing mapreduce job-client jars (see above)
- wrong version (see [Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses-submiting job2remoteClustr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043970/cannot-initialize-cluster-please-check-your-configuration-for-mapreduce-framewo) )
- my configured 'yarn.ipc.client.factory.class' wasn't in the classpath of the yarn server's (just on the client)

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was trying to use sqoop and ran into this error.
Turns out that i was pointing to the latest version of hadoop 2.0 available from CDH repo for which sqoop was not supported.
The version of cloudera was 2.0.0-cdh4.4.0 which had yarn support build in.

When i used 2.0.0-cdh4.4.0 under hadoop-0.20 the problem went away.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

changing mapreduce_shuffle to mapreduce.shuffle made it work in my case