# IOException in my code java

Tags: apache-spark

I use spark using java, whenever I  try to run my code it appears an IOException in this lines of code :

```
     SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").setMaster("local[*]");
     JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

the detail of this exception is :

```
Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```

and when i tried to download winutils.exe and installed it i got this message :

```
the program cant start bcz MSVCR100.dll is misssing
```

so how can i solve it please?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697744/spark-1-6-failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `HADOOP_HOME` variable to some path. Place winutils.exe inside `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`.

For the MSVCR100.dll, download it and install.

Make sure, that you download 32 bit/64 bit winutils.exe and dll as per your machine configuration.

Here is the link to setup spark on windows:
[How to run Apache Spark on Windows7 in standalone mode](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html)

Hope it helps you..

Comment: i set the variable and i installed .dll file , honestly i dont know how to do this correctly, would u give me a link bcz i followed what i found in youtube but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

finally i fixed this  issue , i just followed the way explained in this link , it s easy and clear and efficient 
link: 
http://teknosrc.com/spark-error-java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-hadoop-binaries/
wanna thank you #Nishu Tayal