# Getting issue on Spark-standalone and Java application

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to develop an application with Spark and getting following errors while executing on myeclispe.

I have added all dependency jars into the application after that also I am getting this errors.

> ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the Hadoop binary
> path java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable
> null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
>
> Exception in thread **"main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/spark/network/client/StreamCallback** Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.spark.network.client.StreamCallback

Please help me on this and suggest to me how to overcome from these issues.

Comment: There are multiple answers on SO regarding your winutils.exe problem, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697744/spark-1-6-failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path

Comment: @BinaryNerd , In my system, I already configured  winutils.exe and it's working fine on Scala and basic java programs. While trying to integrating with Spark and Java2EE application.

Comment: Neither Java or Scala specifically need winutils, Spark/Hadoop need it. The `null` in the path tells me you're not setting `hadoop.home.dir`.

Comment: Thanks @BinaryNerd   for you help and it is working now after tried with winutils..