# ERROR Shell:397 - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

When trying to configure the spark appears this error, already consulted other posts, but I could not solve the problem, can anyone help me?

[ERROR Shell:397 - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable C:\WinUtils\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5s7R.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark 1.6-Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697744/spark-1-6-failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path)

Comment: Is win-utils in the right directory?