# log4j.properties in SPARK 2.4.4

Tags: python, apache-spark

I installed Spark Apache 2.4.4 with Python 3.7.6, this installation works but the problem is that it makes me several errors especially the log4j one that I would like to fix. 
I followed these instructions but the error is still displayed.

" Set the log4j.rootCategory property value to WARN, console.
 Save the log4j.properties file."

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download winutils.exe.Path https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils

This is required to run spark in windows.and keep it in path (create path if not present)
C:\winutils\bin.

Reference [Spark 1.6-Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697744/spark-1-6-failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path)

Comment: it's good for this error but the other one still exists on the log4j!