# How to sumit a mapreduce job to remote cluster configured with yarn?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to execute a simple mapreduce program from eclipse .Following is my program

```
package wordcount;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020");
        conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
        conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "quickstart.cloudera:8032");
        conf.set("yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir", "/user");
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0-cdh5.7.0.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0-cdh5.7.0.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.7.0.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0-cdh5.7.0.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0-cdh5.7.0.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0-cdh5.7.0.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/commons-logging-1.2.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/guava-15.0.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/commons-configuration-1.7.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/commons-lang-2.6.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/log4j-1.2.16.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"));
        job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar"));
        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/test.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/user/cloudera/prasad/wordout2"));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

Initially when I run the above program, it was throwing some ClassNotFoundExceptions in container log, so I have added all the corresponding jars as written in the program.Now its not showing any errors in container log but it is the mapreduce job is getting failed.

But resource manager showing the below error

```
Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_1473338609943_0003_01_000001 and exit code: 1
ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:738)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

when I click on application log it is not showing anything just displaying the following message.

```
 Log Type: stderr

Log Upload Time: Thu Sep 08 05:26:35 -0700 2016

Log Length: 243

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.


Log Type: stdout

Log Upload Time: Thu Sep 08 05:26:35 -0700 2016

Log Length: 0
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my program.

Following are screens of libs I am using
[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]

Comment: Those JAR files are to be placed on HDFS for the classpath, not necessarily bundled with your application. What command did you use to run the job?

Comment: yeah I alreay placed all the jars in the given location in hdfs.And I am not running any command just executing it from eclipse as java application.

Comment: I see. Typically, I bundle the project as a jar, then use the `hadoop jar` command.

Comment: In order to see the error in your application, you have to add a log4j.properties file under src/main/resources. For example files check [here](https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/)

Comment: @prasad seems like you are still missing dependencies in Eclipse. Attach the screenshot or the listing of the `Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries` window.. It is very tricky though to get what you are missing without proper debugging. Are you using any build system like Maven or Gradle for your project?

Comment: Hi @Serhiy, Thanks for your prompt response.I have edited my question and added the screens as you said.And I am not using the Build tools  Maven or Gradle